# jquery datepicker disable specific dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am trying to create a datepicker that would read some variable and disable that date in that variable.

Currently following this documentation by
http://t1m0n.name/air-datepicker/docs/#example-custom-content

but i can't seem to understand much about the OnRenderCell: function

how can i make it disable a specific date say july 16, 2016

```
 onRenderCell: function (date, cellType) {
    if (cellType == 'month') {
        var day = date.getDay(),
            isDisabled = disabledDays.indexOf(day) != -1;

        return {
            disabled: isDisabled
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var disabled_months = ["2016-1-1", "2016-2-1", "2016-6-1"];
var disabled_days   = ["2016-6-1", "2016-6-3", "2016-6-20"];
var disabled_years  = ["2014-1-1", "2013-1-1", "2000-1-1"];

$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    language: 'en',
    onRenderCell: function (date, cellType) {
        pretty_date = date.getFullYear() + '-' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + date.getDate();
        var disabled = false

        if (cellType == 'month')
            disabled = disabled_months.indexOf(pretty_date) != -1

        else if (cellType == 'day')
            disabled = disabled_days.indexOf(pretty_date) != -1

        else if (cellType == 'year')
            disabled = disabled_years.indexOf(pretty_date) != -1

        return {disabled: disabled}
    }
});
```